# How to connect from a docker container to a published port in another container

Tags: docker

I have a *Registry* in a Docker container and a TeamCity *Agent* in another container. *Agent* has to pull an image from *Registry* during the build process. *Registry* is running on a machine mapped to `image-repo` name, and the standard port 5000 is mapped to 55000 (via `docker-compose` file).

It all goes fine if *Agent* is running on a different machine (an *Ubuntu*) than *Registry* (which runs on a *Raspberry Pi*) - then it can connect to *Registry* via `image-repo:55000`, and I didn't have to do anything to get it working.

But when *Agent* is running on the same machine as *Registry*, it cannot find *Registry* by name `image-repo:55000`, the name `image-repo` is not recognizable by `ping`. If I connect these two images with `docker network` (*bridge*), the name `image-repo` becomes accessible, but then the opened port is 5000, not 55000.

The question is: how can I connect to *Registry* from *Agent*, when they run on the same machine, via *Registry*'s published (not internal) port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we are talking about a docker registry, the answer will be different than the normal answer. From the docker client, when you push and pull an image, that request is sent to the docker daemon (dockerd) and it's the responsibility of that daemon to resolve the hostname and connect to the port. This common scenario of talking to a docker daemon from inside of a container is to mount the docker socket (/var/run/docker.sock) and connect to the daemon on the host. If you've done this, then the registry port needs to be published, and you can communicate with that via "localhost", "127.0.0.1", or the hostname, using the published port.

If you happen to be using Docker in Docker (DinD), with a privileged container and a separate dockerd process running inside of a container, then that DinD container needs to be on the same network as your registry container, and you access it via the registry container name as the hostname, and connect to the registry port directly, not to the published port.

Comment: That seems to be my mistake. I had a step to verify that the repository is accessible (as I had some connection troubles in the beginning), and that check was done with `curl`. And I assumed that if `curl` can't find the repository, then `docker` wouldn't either.

Now I disabled that step, and off it goes. This solves the problem at hand.

For the reference, though - how can I make `curl` access `image-repo:55000` from within the *Agent* container?

Comment: Curl runs in the container rather than the docker host. In that case the second scenario applies, use the container name for DNS and the container port, not the published port. This requires both containers to be in the same user created docker network.

Comment: Is it possible to access a published port from a container?

Comment: Depends on the firewall rules and DNS resolution. You can't use localhost since that's unique to each container and different than the host. But putting in the host ip/name and published port should work the same as an external connection to the host.

Comment: I tried - but `curl image-repo:55000` didn't work, though `curl image-repo:5000` does in a setup where the two images are connected via Docker network.

Comment: Sounds like `image-repo` is the name of your container. You won't be able to reach the host with that name, even if the host is named the same as the container. DNS will resolve the container before going to external DNS.